# Python CGI program just outputs the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I have just started studying python web development and thought i'd start with CGI. So i wrote a simple cgi script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
print('Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n')
print('<html>')
print('<head>')
print('<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>')
print('</head>')
print('<body>')
print('<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

I am using Python3.5. To enable CGI on my computer (Windows 10), I configured cgi-bin for the website from IIS for applications to run with 'python.exe'. Here are my settings :

```
Request path : *.py
Executable : C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe
Name : Python
```

Now I am calling this script from another HTML file through a hyperlink that is included in this website but it just outputs the whole code and not the html output. What should i do?

If you require additional settings, then just comment and i'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: You may need to wrap the `"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe"` in double quotes to protect the space in it.

Comment: You might have better luck asking at Stack Overflow's sister site: [sf]

Comment: I didn' t get anything at Server Fault except for the fact that Windows 10 is not a server OS